# How to create Multi-Module project on Maven?

Tags: spring, maven

I am trying to make a new multi-module Spring project with Maven. I have one main Pom.xml, and to other modules.

This is the main pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.ev</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>main</module>
        <module>user</module>
    </modules>
```

And this is the module1 pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>multi</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.ev</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>user</artifactId>


</project>
```

Where should i add the dependencies? When i put them into main pom.xml , i get an error "cant resolve pom" .

[image: Project]

Do you have any idea about this issue? Because its very hard to create multi module project for me.

Comment: First try to build in command line... from root level ... `mvn clean package`. does that work?

Comment: error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar is missing. @ line 17, column 21
@khmarbaise

Comment: That means you have not posted the poms your are using....

Comment: you need to decide if you inherit from the spring boot parent or if you want only one of the modules to contain the spring boot libraries (so not using the spring boot parent pom), see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.4/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.parent-pom

Answer (score 0):

try to change  `main/pom.xml`

```
<artifactId>multi</artifactId>
```

to

```
<artifactId>main</artifactId>
```